# stop sounds after going back to the previous tab

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a simple tabbed app where the user can click a button and then a view will load in the active tab where a picture is displayed and a sound is being played.
However if the user tabs on the back button the sound doesn't stop playing.

How can I make the sound stop when I go to the previous view?
Thanks in advance!

My index.js:

```js
function viewSelectedItem() {
 
 var args = { image : 'images/photo/farm/chicken1.jpg', title : 'kip' };
  var win = Alloy.createController('viewItem', args).getView();
    Alloy.Globals.tabgroup.activeTab.open(win);
}
```

my viewItem.js

```js
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.itemImage.image = args.image;
$.itemTextLabel.text = args.title;

var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({ 
    url: 'sounds/farm/chicken1.mp3'
});

sound.play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
    $.itemView.addEventListener('close', windowClosed);
    function windowClosed() {
      sound.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you target Android with this and that each Alloy Controller represents a Window.

You need to set `allowBackground` to `true` to allow the audio to continue when the Activity the Window belongs to is stopped because the Window closed.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer-property-allowBackground

Comment: Thanks for your response Fokke, I target iOS and Android. Is there a solution for both platforms?